# ¿Cómo podría poner una condición para que solo me acepte números diferentes y no repetidos, en Java?

Tags: java, condiciones, lógica

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño de su agrreglo");
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cantidad_num;
    cantidad_num = leer.nextInt();
    int[] Arr_numeros;
    int aux = 0;
    Arr_numeros = new int[cantidad_num];
    System.out.println("Ingrese numeros");

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_num; i++) {
        aux = aux + Arr_numeros[i];
        Arr_numeros[i] = leer.nextInt();

    }

    System.out.println("Sus numeros son : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_num; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arr_numeros[i]);
    }

}
```

Me gustaría saber cómo podría ponerle una condición para que pida solo números diferentes y no repetidos. De igual manera que me salga un mensaje que me diga que ingrese números diferentes.

Comment: Puedes crear un método que simule un ***indexOf*** y si el número se encuentra, disminuir el incremento de i en 1 para que vuelva a leer la misma posición. Tal vez te sirva [este tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-index-of-an-array-element-in-java/) de GeeksForGeeks

Answer (score 1):

A ver si te sirve:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Pedimos la longitud del array
    System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño de su agrreglo");

    //variable entera para la cantidad que lee por teclado
    int cantidad_num = leer.nextInt();
    
    //declaramos el array con la longitud que tendrá
    int[] Arr_numeros = new int[cantidad_num];
    //variable para recoger la suma de sus valores
    int sum = 0;

    //pedimos los valores del array
    System.out.println("Ingrese los numeros del array");
    //bucle para pedir valores
    for (int i = 0; i < Arr_numeros.length; i++) {
        //vamos pidiendo valores e informando de cual
        System.out.println("Número " + (i + 1) + " de " + Arr_numeros.length);
        //recogemos valor en variable auxiliar
        int aux = leer.nextInt();
        //bucle para recorrer array
        for (int j = 0; j < Arr_numeros.length; j++){
            //evaluamos que el valor no se repita
            if (aux == Arr_numeros[j]){
                //si se repite informamos
                System.out.println("Número utilizado, elija otro");
                //descontamos uno a la variable del bucle
                i--;     
                break;             
            }               
        }
        //si no se repite añadimos el valor al array
        Arr_numeros[i] = aux;
    }
    //imprimimos los valores del array
    System.out.println("Sus numeros son : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < Arr_numeros.length - 1; i++) {
        //aprovechaos el bucle de impresión de valores para sumarlos
        sum += Arr_numeros[i];
        System.out.print(Arr_numeros[i] + ", ");
    }
    //sumamos el último valor que habíamos dejado fuera del bucle
    sum += (Arr_numeros[Arr_numeros.length - 1]);
    /imprimimos el último valor que habíamos dejado fuera del bucle
    System.out.println(Arr_numeros[Arr_numeros.length - 1]);
    //damos el valor de la suma de los valores del bucle
    System.out.println("La suma de sus valores es de: " + sum);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
}
```

Comment: Mete un break dentro del if, para que no te siga iterando

Comment: Te refieres a meter el break eliminando i--; ?

Comment: No, después del i-- poner un break; pues ya no va a ser necesario seguir iterando

Comment: Ahh, ok ok, editado y agregado. Vale, ahora lo entendí, en el momento que encuentre una coincidencia, no es necesario que recorra el resto de valores. Gracias @EduardoJiménez

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de alguna de las clases que implementan la interfaz Set, como HashSet, que guardan un listado de objetos y no permiten duplicados. Por ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  // Pedimos la longitud del array
  System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño de su agreglo");
  // variable entera para la cantidad que lee por teclado
  int cantidadPedidos = leer.nextInt();

  Set<Integer> valores = new LinkedHashSet<>(cantidadPedidos);
  while (valores.size() < cantidadPedidos) {
    int cantidadIntroducidos = valores.size();
    System.out.println("Número " + (valores.size() + 1) + " de " + cantidadPedidos);
    valores.add(leer.nextInt());
    
    // Si la cantidad de valores no ha cambiado, es porque ha introducido un valor que ya estaba        
    if (cantidadIntroducidos == valores.size()) {
      System.out.println("Número utilizado, elija otro");
    }
  }
}
```